# Map dto to complex entity

Tags: c#, automapper, dto, automapper-3

How can I map the complex UploadDTO to the entity Number?

```
public class UploadDTO
{
    public CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
    public MachineDTO Machine { get; set; }
    public NumberDTO Number { get; set; }
}

public class Number
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Machine Machine { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDTO , Customer >();
 Mapper.CreateMap<MachineDTO , Machine >();
 Mapper.CreateMap<NumberDTO , Number>();
```

Problem is that the UploadDTO mapping is missing so it does not work. But how can I say:*"take UploadDTO.Customer TO Customer for example?"*

Comment: see above what I did

Comment: You aren't creating a map from `UploadDTO` to `Number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the missing mapping from UploadDTO to Number:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UploadDTO , Number>();
```